# Safari does not always draw an svg line when its position is changed

Tags: html, css, svg, safari

I have an SVG element with a line:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <line x1="0" y1="0.5" x2="1" y2="0.5" />
</svg>
```

I want to move the line vertically when the user presses left mouse button on the image and drags the mouse while holding the button. When dragging the mouse cursor, the line is not always shown by Safari (the line is flickering). However, it works fine in Chrome and Firefox. Why is it not working in Safari?

A workaround is to add a border to the svg element. Why does this workaround work? Is there another way to fix it?

I'm using Safari Version 16.1 (18614.2.9.1.12) on macOS 13.0.1 (22A400).

To view the demo, click "Run code snippet" button and click near the vertical line to move it and drag the mouse cursor while holding the left mouse button.

```js
class Input {
  constructor($element, $line) {
    this.$element = $element;
    this.$line = $line;

    // Function that is called when user clicks the fundus is moved,
    // passing position as argument
    this.onChange = null;

    // True if the user holds left mouse bottom, which
    // indicates that frame is being changed.
    // False by default or when the left mouse button is released.
    this.active = false;

    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    let $element = this.$element;

    // Start changing brightness
    // -----------------

    $element.onmousedown = (e) => {
      if (e.button !== 0) return; // Not a left mouse button
      this.active = true;
      e.preventDefault();
      this.handleClick(e);
    };

    $element.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
      this.active = true;
      e.preventDefault();
      this.handleClick(e);
    });

    // End changing brightness
    // -----------------

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
      this.active = false;
    });

    document.addEventListener("touchend", () => {
      this.active = false;
    });

    // Drag the pointer over the bar
    // -----------------

    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      if (!this.active) return;
      this.handleClick(e);
    });

    document.addEventListener("touchmove", (e) => {
      if (!this.active) return;
      this.handleClick(e);
    });
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    let position = this.positionFromCursor(e);
    this.$line.setAttribute("y1", position);
    this.$line.setAttribute("y2", position);
  }

  // Returns a number from 0 to 1 corresponding to the
  // position of the cursor relative to the bscan box on fundus image
  positionFromCursor(e) {
    let $element = this.$element;
    // Vertical position of the click relative to the viewport.
    var pointerY = e.clientY;

    if (e.touches && e.touches.length > 0) {
      pointerY = e.touches[0].clientY;
    }

    var elementTop = $element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    pointerY = pointerY - elementTop;
    let height = $element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - elementTop;

    if (pointerY > height) {
      // Can not be larger than size of the element
      pointerY = height;
    }

    if (pointerY < 0) {
      // Can not be negative
      pointerY = 0;
    }

    return pointerY / height;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const $svgElement = document.querySelector(".Svg");
  const $svgLine = document.querySelector(".Svg-line");
  new Input($svgElement, $svgLine);
});
```

```css
.Svg {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  /* Workaround for Safari to show the line */
  /* border: 5px solid red; */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Svg-line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 0.02px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="Svg" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <line class="Svg-line" x1="0" y1="0.5" x2="1" y2="0.5" />
</svg>
```

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org (and if you need a workaround, avoid rounding issues and use a bigger range than [0, 1].)

Comment: A possibly less disruptive workaround is to set the `<svg>` background-color. And if you do set a `filter: blur(2px)` on the `<svg>` without workarounds you can see better the rendering is broken.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, changing the viewBox to "0 0 100 100" fixed the issue in Safari. No workaround needed. https://codepen.io/evgenyneu/pen/bGjgMzJ

Comment: You can write it as an answer @Kaiido if you want me to accept it.